# Rails 5 - undefined local variable or method `post'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, ruby-on-rails-5, model-associations

I'm new to Rails. I've created a category model for my posts but when I go to display all posts associated with a particular category I get a NameError page

Here's my categories `show.html.erb` file:

```
<h1> <%= "Category: " + @category.name %></h1>

<div align="center">
  <%= will_paginate @category_posts %>
</div>

<%= render 'posts/post', obj: @category_posts %>

<div align="center">
 <% will_paginate @category_posts %>
</div>
```

I'm rendering the `_post.html.erb` partial to display posts that was defined in my post folder.

Looks like the issue is linked to the first line in the code below because the error message points to `<li id="post-<%= post.id %>">` in the `_post.html.erb` code:

```
<li id="post-<%= post.id %>">

  <span class="title"> <%=link_to post.title, post_path(post) %> </span>
  <span class="content"><%= truncate(post.content, length: 100) if post.content? %></span>
  <span class="content"> <%= image_tag post.picture.url if post.picture? %> </span>

  <span class="content">
    <% if post.category.any? %>
      <p><%= render post.category %></p>
    <% end %>
  </span>

</li>
```

And this is my `category` controller file where I definite the "show" method:

```
class CategorysController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_admin, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @categories = Category.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def new
    @category = Category.new
  end

  def create
    @category = Category.new(category_params)
    if @category.save
      flash[:success] = "Category created successfully"
      redirect_to categories_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @category_posts = @category.posts.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 5)
  end
```

The Post model:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
  has_many :post_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :post_category

  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true
  validate :picture_size

  private
    # validates the size of an upload picture
    def picture_size
      if picture.size > 5.megabytes
        errors.add(:picture, "should be less than 5MB")
      end
    end
end
```

The general idea is that when I go to `localhost/categories/1` for example, I should have all the posts associated with that category.
Can anyone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: You have `<% render 'posts/post', obj: @category_posts %>` which should be `<%= render 'posts/post', obj: @category_posts %>`. Is it a typo?

Comment: That's a typo. I forgot the `=`

Comment: I haven't worked with partials using the `object` way of passing in locals. Does it actually work as expected when the partial path has a directory in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably mean to render a [partial using a collection](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials):

```
render(partial: 'posts/post', collection: @category_posts)
```

Where that should expand that partial to repeat once for each post and assign the local `post` variable.

`obj` isn't a valid argument, but `object` is if you want to render the content once with a given object.